# How to fix IWbemLocator::ConnectServer returning E_ACCESSDENIED?

Tags: c++, wmi

My goal is simple: to establish a WMI connection to a remote machine. A small test program shows that what was working since the WinXP era is now outdated. With WMI hardening update, WMI clients are expected to use the `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY` authentication level. But just changing it in code, apparently, does not solves the problem.

Test setup:

- developer machine: Windows 7 SP 1, VS 2022.
- remote machine: Windows 10 LTS.

Given the following code:

```cpp
// Compile with cl /std:c++17 or later
#include <wbemcli.h>
#include <string_view>

#pragma comment (lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "OleAut32.lib")

#define IP      L"192.168.1.2"
#define LOGIN   L"Administrator"
#define PWD     L"P@ssw0rd"

using namespace std::literals;

::BSTR SysString (std::wstring_view data) {
    return ::SysAllocStringLen (data.data (), (UINT) data.size ());
    }

int main (void) {
    ::wprintf (L"CoInitializeEx -> 0x%08X\n", ::CoInitializeEx (nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));
    ::wprintf (L"CoInitializeSecurity -> 0x%08X\n", ::CoInitializeSecurity (
        nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        nullptr, EOAC_NONE, nullptr
        ));
    ::IWbemLocator *wmiLocator = nullptr;
    ::wprintf (L"CoCreateInstance -> 0x%08X\n", ::CoCreateInstance (
        CLSID_WbemLocator, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (void **) &wmiLocator
        ));
    if (wmiLocator) {
        ::IWbemServices *pNamespace = nullptr;
        ::wprintf (L"ConnectServer -> 0x%08X\n", wmiLocator->ConnectServer (
            SysString (L"\\\\" IP L"\\root\\cimv2"sv),
            SysString (IP L"\\" LOGIN L""sv),
            SysString (PWD L""sv),
            nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &pNamespace
            ));
        if (pNamespace)
            pNamespace->Release ();
        wmiLocator->Release ();
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
CoInitializeEx -> 0x00000000
CoInitializeSecurity -> 0x00000000
CoCreateInstance -> 0x00000000
ConnectServer -> 0x80070005
```

Also, on the target machine, an event with the code 10036 gets created (the one about client applications requiring at least `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY`) with both valid and invalid passwords.

I also tried setting `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY` instead of `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY`, with the same result.

Comment: On a side note: you are leaking all of your `BSTR`s, you need to free them when you are done using them.

Comment: What does the Security Event Log on the server say?

Comment: Also, are the machines domain-joined or not? For me your code works with win11 client to windows server 2022 with domain admin credentials.

Comment: @IgorLevicki , it gives DCOM event 10036 about requiering client to use at least RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY. It's not in english on the test machine and i'm not sure I will correctly translate them. And no, they are not in domain.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this program is just for testing and demonstration purposes, therefore I cut some error processing and resource management parts.

Answer (score -1):

I used 4 machines for testing:

1. Domain-joined Windows 11 workstation
2. Windows Server 2022 which is a PDC for domain-joined Windows 11 workstation
3. Standalone Windows 11 workstation (first VM)
4. Standalone Windows 7 SP1 workstation (second VM)

I tested the following scenarios with your code:

- 1 -> 2 using Domain Administrator account — SUCCESS
- 1 -> 3 using Local Administrator account — SUCCESS
- 4 -> 2 using Domain Administrator account — FAILURE
- 4 -> 3 using Local Administrator account — FAILURE

Even after configuring computer-wide DCOM security level to Packet Integrity using `dcomcnfg.exe` on Windows 7 SP1 and restarting the connection was still being denied.

Based on test results it seems that Windows 7 SP1, for which Microsoft has not released a DCOM Security Bypass hotfix (a fix for CVE-2021-26414), is uncapable of connecting to computers running operating systems which have received this hotfix.

To make sure that your code isn't the problem, I have also tested from Windows 7 SP1 using WMIC command line tool and it fails with the same error even if you specify `/authlevel:Pktintegrity` along with correct credentials.

For more details, see this Microsoft [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c) (check the OS table to see the relevant hotfix KB numbers for each of them).

TL;DR — Your code should work from a different client OS, but if you need it to work from Windows 7 SP1 then you seem to be out of luck.